# How to fetch data using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline, scrapy-shell

I am working on a Django project and I want to provide some news feeds to the home page. I recently got interact with scrapy, when I run given code with "scarpy shell", this code is able to fetch the data successfully. But when I put this code into a script to automate the newsfeed to the template this code wont work and raise "error fetch is not define"

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import *

fetch("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cholera&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa")

news_links = response.css(".r").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
news_texts = response.css(".st").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
news_images = response.css(".th").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
```

I have tried this:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cholera&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa']

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.css(".r").extract()
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

with the command:

```
scrapy crawl quotes
```

Which is also not working, How can I transform  this code into a script.

Error log:

```
scrapy crawl news
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: newsfee)
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_M}
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pa)
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening 4
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.)
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden b>
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 224,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2348,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 22, 8, 54, 33, 954793),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 65478656,
 'memusage/startup': 65478656,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 22, 8, 54, 33, 295945)}
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.)
2017-12-22 14:24:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden b>
```

from this two lines log,it should have forbidden by google.

I think you need to firstly add up some more flexible and effective methods to [avoid getting banned](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned).

Besides that,you can first use `scrapy shell <url>` to [debug or test your scrapying url directly](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#using-the-shell).

Comment: what the work sucessfully mean? Can fetch the info you want?

Comment: I tried through `view(response)`,but the response dont exist body attribute